# innerHTML Isn't working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript

I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple here but can't seem to find it.

I'm using SwfUpload and on its `uploadSuccess()` event, I'm showing a "success" message on the screen while hiding the progress image.  Below is the snippet:

```
swfu.uploadSuccess = function(file, serverData, response) {
    document.getElementById("progressImg").display = "none";

    var uploadMessage = document.getElementById("UploadMessage");
    uploadMessage.style.display = "block";
    uploadMessage.innerHTML("The file, " + file.name + ", was uploaded successfully.");                 
};
```

Everything works fine up until the last line when I'm attempting to set the text of the `uploadMessage` object.  The object refers to a `<span>` tag though I've also tried it as a `<div>` just in case.  IE8 says that `innerHTML` is not supported and FF3.5.4 doesn't show any errors (haven't added firebug yet).  I've also tried to just put set static text instead of a concatenated string to no avail either.

This is a trivial task that I've done countless times w/ and w/o a framework; however, it's not working at this time.  What am I missing?

Thanks

EDIT:

Since someone may wonder, current doctype is set to HTML 4.0 Transitional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a property:

```
 uploadMessage.innerHTML = "...";
```

On a side note, have you considered what happens if name of file contains an ampersand?

Comment: Thanks.  I knew it was something completely stupid and simple and just needed a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML is a property, not a method, that's it :)

So uploadMessage.innerHTML = "...";

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
uploadMessage.innerHTML = "The file, " + file.name + ", was uploaded successfully.";

Comment: Here is one example how to use innerHTML http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php